Pydatic-Settings 2.6.0 - declare the env file and different Pydantic model wrapped in AppConfig
I am new to Pydantic and I am trying to use pydantic-settings to load my .env file.
Below is the code:
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


# Use BaseSettings instead of BaseModel for UserConfig
class UserConfig(BaseSettings):
    user: str = Field(..., env="MY_USER")
    user_pwd: str = Field(..., env="MY_USER_PWD")

    # Explicitly specify config to load environment
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env.local")


class AppConfig(BaseSettings):
    log_level: str = Field(..., env="LOG_LEVEL")
    log_file: str = Field(..., env="LOG_FILE")

    # Field for nested settings with default_factory
    user_config: UserConfig = Field(default_factory=UserConfig)

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file='.env.local')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = AppConfig()
    print(config.dict())

And below are the entries in my .env.local file:
MY_USER=abcd
MY_USER_PWD=system
LOG_LEVEL=INFO
LOG_FILE=app

However, I am not able to load the below variable (nested one):
user_config: UserConfig = Field(default_factory=UserConfig)
If I comment this and remove the corresponding key-value from .env file, it works fine.
Seems like, I am missing something here or it might be an pydantic-settings module issue. It might not work well in nested case. I am using 2.6.0 version of pydantic-settings
My goal was to declare the env file and different Pydantic model wrapped in AppConfig.
Could anyone help me here?
Thanks in advance.

I see what you're trying to do, but you should keep in mind that .env files have no substructures. So in order to create such a structure for you application, you'd have to do some extra work, to split the variables onto different classes.
Some further notes:

You can use alias instead of env inside the field definitions. It's more "pydantic".
Only the top class, the class loading the environment, needs to inherit from BaseSettings. The others can derive from BaseModel.
.dict() is from pydantic v1. Use .model_dump instead.

A mwe could look like this:
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel, model_validator
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class UserConfig(BaseModel):
    user: str = Field(..., alias="MY_USER")
    user_pwd: str = Field(..., alias="MY_USER_PWD")


class LoggingConfig(BaseModel):
    log_level: str = Field(..., alias="LOG_LEVEL")
    log_file: str = Field(..., alias="LOG_FILE")


class AppConfig(BaseSettings):
    user_config: UserConfig
    logging_config: LoggingConfig

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env.local", case_sensitive=True)

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def create_sub_structure(cls, values):
        return {
            "user_config": values,
            "logging_config": values,
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = AppConfig()
    print(config.model_dump(mode="json"))

You can simply put all values inside the sub-configs because pydantic will ignore any extra fields in this case. You need case_sensitive=True here, because otherwise the field_names will be transformed to lowercase by the pydantic-settings framework which will result in errors in the sub-configs.

This looks great. Thanks for the solution. I will test and update you on this.
